How to "inject" a profile into a firefox running inside a python container?
I am trying to run a "webcrawler" that impersonates a profile I have in my "host" machine. This profile contains a google session that would allow me to make requests to the site. It also copies the cookies and other tokens; the program works fine in my machine. The problem is that I don't know how to pass it to the firefox instance running inside the container.
The scripts are based in Python, using Selenium and GeckoDriver. The container is very simple:
FROM python:3.11.8-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install firefox-esr -y
# Install Python packages
RUN pip install selenium webdriver_manager

ENV DISPLAY=:0

# Copy Python script
COPY main.py .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]


I tried to search for the location where profiles are stored to no success.
I have also tried to "bruteforce" the program to tell me where the profiles are stored by loading about:profiles but the site tells me there has been a problem loading profiles and that I should try to reload firefox.

